# Chromium doesn't display Flash in Debian Wheezy

Tags: chrome, debian, adobe-flash

Since Google phased out the NPAPI, it cannot use `flashplugin-nonfree`. I understand it needs to use `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, but it's not available in the repos.

Is it because of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`? It looks like that now:

```
deb http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Any changes I should make there? Or how do I install pepperflashplugin-nonfree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You answered your own question, pepperflashplugin-nonfree is the way to go.

In your case, you need to enable the wheezy-backports repository, adding the following line to your sources.list:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then, update the list of available packages with `apt-get update`, and finally install it with

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Comment: Yes, I read on [wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer/Installing) about `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, but it somehow not working for me. It downloads `google-chrome-stable` and unpack `libpepflashplayer.so` (shared library), save it and configure `chromium` to use it. (It seems it also install `google-chrome-stable` not sure about it, I might install it myself.). `PepperFlashPlayer` works so far only with `google-chrome-stable`.